# ASP.NET MVC errors in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view

[image]

I am using ASP.NET MVC / C# but my views are full of errors.

At runtime, I don't get any error but my screen is full of red underlines. In the error panel, I get the attached error. Can you help me to install what is missing in my Visual Studio?

Comment: may be you should clean your project and clean debug folder manually, if it can't fix it create an empty project and move your code to new one

Answer (score 0):

if using vs this happens a lot. Close and reopen always worked to me